# Jquery Redirect inmediatly after Session Timeout

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, session

I have a web in ASP.NET MVC and I want to redirect to login page automatically after session timeout without the user intervention. For example like gmail does.

Now I'm doing ajax calls to the controller to check session in intervals of 5 seconds.

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CheckSession(string currentUrl)
        {
            bool result = false;
            Uri url = new Uri(currentUrl);
            if (PublicUrl.Contains(url.AbsolutePath))
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }
            return Json(result);
        }
```

And if the result is false I do a redirect on JQuery.

This works well if I manually delete the cookies on the browser. But the problem is that the session never expires because I'm doing calls to server each 5 seconds so the session timeout resets on every server side call.

How can I redirect on Session expiry automatically?

Comment: There are two separate concerns here: server session timeout, and client side awareness of server session timeout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several separate concerns here: server session timeout, and client side awareness of server session timeout, and doing something on user inactivity.

1) How you implementing session timeout on the server side?
2) Since you are keeping the session alive with your heartbeat (every 5 seconds) you probably never reach session timeout on the server.

You can manage this on the client side only, by making a logout call with JavaScript once the timeout value is reached.  Use window.setTimeout() to set the inactivity timeout on the client side.  When the timer fires, redirect the browser to either the logout controller, or a sessionExpired controller (your choice). Clear the timer using the beforeUnload event, and set a new one on page load.

Then, let the server timeout value deal with the case where the user closes browser and heartbeat stops.

Excerpt from web.config that defines my session timeout to 20 minutes:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" name="ilApp" requireSSL="false" defaultUrl="~/Account/Login" />
   </authentication>
   <sessionState timeout="20" />
```

And javascript code that I added to /Shared/_Layout.cshtml as this file is included in every page on my site:

```
    @* Redirect browser to session expiration page on timeout *@
    @{
        var authenticationSettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/authentication") as System.Web.Configuration.AuthenticationSection;
    }
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function ilSessionTimeout() {
                window.location = '@Url.Action("SessionExpired", "Account", new { area = "" })';
            };
            function ilSessionTimeoutWarning() {
                $.jGrowl('You will be logged off soon due to inactivity.', { sticky: true, theme: 'growl-warning', header: 'Attention' });
            };
            // remember our timers so we can cancel when we unload this page and reset them on the next page load
            var g_pageTimer = window.setTimeout(ilSessionTimeout, @authenticationSettings.Forms.Timeout.TotalMilliseconds);
            var g_pageTimerWarning = window.setTimeout(ilSessionTimeoutWarning, Math.round(@authenticationSettings.Forms.Timeout.TotalMilliseconds*0.8));
            // clean up anything that needs cleaning before we leave this page
            window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
                // clear the timers
                window.clearTimeout(g_pageTimer);
                window.clearTimeout(g_pageTimerWarning);
            };
        });
    </script>
```

This sets two timers, one for the session timeout period (based on the value defined in web.config) and a second one at 80% expiration to show a warning message using jGrowl.  I keep a handle to both timers in javascript global variables (g_pageTimer*) for the unload event.

I hooked into window.onbeforeunload to make sure I cancel my timers when the page is about to change.  Without this, the timeout is absolute a redirects to logout regardless of client-side activity.

When timeout timer fires, I redirect to a page on my site, /Account/SessionExpired that shows a message to the user and then completes the logoff.  In my example, I am using ASP.Net Identity 2, but whatever you normally do during logoff, you do here.

```
    // 
    // GET: /Account/SessionExpired
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SessionExpired()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAll(); // Remove all session variables that we used
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        }
        catch
        {
            // do nothing
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I' m su ing the web.config to set the server session time out. What do you mean with reset the timer on before unload event ?

Comment: Good question. I've added some code to clarify my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. This is too much clear. Finally what do you mean with this? "Then, let the server timeout value deal with the case where the user closes browser and heartbeat stops"

Comment: With your ajax heartbeat running every 5 seconds (or whatever periodicity) the server will not time out until the client stops the heartbeat.  Then after your server timeout period, the server will time out.

In my example you are letting the client-side timer (via javascript) cause the inactivity timeout (in my example it's driven by page load activity only.  You might want to add other events that restart the timers such as keydown or mouse).

And, if the user closes the browser (in which case heartbeat stops and the timers are erased) the server will still do its timeout.

Comment: Ok. I didn't understand you well because I was thinking in delete my heartbeat because it was done to check session but with your idea this is not necessary to me. If window.timeout fires I will do the call to server and if the user closes the browser the session will be closed by server as usually.

Comment: I hope I was able to help you.  If so, please mark this as the answer to close this question.  It also helps others find the answer more easily if you mark it as an answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for my delay in reply. I have implemented this and it works well the idea. I have two corrections. Check is user is authenticated before Url.Action using User.Identity.IsAuthenticated to avoid requests to server every time the timer is reached when the  user is loged out. Another corrections is to use TotalMillisecons insted of Milliseconds. This is a mistake because Millisecons is the Millisecons of the TimeSpan object.

Comment: Now I have another question. When I was using my heartbeat in the error part of AJAX request I have show some message to the user to advise that the connection to the server is lost.  How can I use some heartbeat to check if server is online and advise the user that the server is offline without affecting the session timeout, something like a ping or similar.

Comment: Juan, that is a different question.  I suggest you post it separately for clarity.